# jQuery using array data within an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to get my head around arrays in jQuery. Let's take the following scenario. I have an array of data, like so:

```
var myVariable = [
    'key1' : 'value1',
    'key2' : 'value2',
    'key3' : 'value3',
    'key4' : 'value4'
]
```

And here is a list of elements:

```
<ul id="elem">
    <li class="key1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="key2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="key3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="key4">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**How would I go about creating an `if statement` to run through each element, if the class is identified in the array then replace the text content?** So the final output should be:

```
<ul id="elem">
    <li class="key1">key1</li>
    <li class="key2">key2</li>
    <li class="key3">key3</li>
    <li class="key4">key4</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried with the following but it doesn't appear to work.

```
$('#elm li').each(function (index) {
    $(this).text(myVariable[index]);
});
```

I realise there aren't associative arrays in JS but I'm not really understanding how it work.

Please point me in the right direct. Thanks!!

Comment: Your variable is a syntax error. The contents look like object properties, but you've used `[ ]` which are for creating arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
$("#elem li").text(function(i, text) {
    return this.className in myVariable
         ? myVariable[this.className] : text;
});
```

Another way:

```
$.each(myVariable, function(key, value) {
    $("#elem li." + key).text(value);
});
```

**N.B.:** In JavaScript arrays with non numeric keys are **objects** and should be surrounded with `{}`, but not with `[]`, as in plain arrays.

Comment: Thanks! I used the second option as I find it easier to read. Is there any real difference between the two approaches that I should be aware of?

Comment: @Sheixt Yes, the first one is much faster :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
var myVariable = {
    'key1' : 'value1',
    'key2' : 'value2',
    'key3' : 'value3',
    'key4' : 'value4'
};
$("#elem li").text(function() {
    return myVariable[this.className] == '' ? this.text(): myVariable[this.className];
});
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hty5v/)
PS: I know it is similar to the first answer, but i have seen it after posted this one:(

Comment: Callback function in `.text()` already have current value in its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#elm li').each( function() {  
    var text = myVariable[ $( this ).className ] ? myVariable[ $( this ).className ] : '';   
    $( this ).text( text );   
});
```